# Execute where clause depending on the column value

Tags: sql

Execute where clause depending on the column value

Hi, so here's my problem.

I need to have a query with a where clause bu the condition is depending on the value of a certain field.

Heres the structure:

ID  NAME    CUSTOMERTYPE    STUDENTNO

basically here;s the lofic:

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTTABLE WHERE ID <> ''AND(NAME <> ''
--CASE WHEN CUSTOMERTYPE='STUDENT' THEN EXCEUTE THIS QUERY:
AND STUDENTNO <> '')    
--ELSE WHEN CUSTOMERTYPE <> 'STUDENT' THEN EXECUTE JUST THIS:
)
```

PLEASE HELP. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Your query is showing some strange design - `ID` and `CUSTOMERTYPE` of type `'string'`, are you sure that it should be done this way?

```
SELECT * 
FROM TRANSACTTABLE 
WHERE ID <> '' AND 
NAME <> '' AND 
(CUSTOMERTYPE <> 'STUDENT' OR STUDENTNO <> '')
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use the IF function like this

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTTABLE
WHERE ID <> '' AND IF(CUSTOMERTYPE='STUDENT',STUDENTNO <> '',1=1)
```